# Image absolute positioning not working when page vertical alignment set to bottom

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

I am using Office 365 Word desktop app. Version 2304 on Windows 10. I've had no problems using absolute positioning of images in word when using the default top vertical alignment (Page Setup > Layout > Vertical alignment). If I select absolute position 0 to the right of/below Page, the image appears top left corner of page as expected.

But, with page vertical alignment set to bottom, image absolute positioning always seems to be relative to text. If I select absolute position 0 again, the image appears at the top of text, and if I add or remove lines of text the image shifts accordingly. If I manually drag the image to a position like the top left corner, the absolute position is usually set to a random negative amount (well not quite random, it seems to be an offset from the text), and the image will still shift if I add or remove text lines.

Text wrapping is set to behind text in both cases.

Is this a bug or am I missing something? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could find, this is not a bug but a "feature".
Below is an explanation.

From my tests, when you insert an image, Word actually creates an
"object anchor" whose purpose is to anchor the image to the text at the
current paragraph. (Don't ask me why, it just works this way.)

You may see this anchor by entering the picture's format dialog,
Layout tab, click Advanced, and under Options enable "Lock anchor".
It will look like this : [image].

The problem is that this anchor stays in its place and there
is absolutely no way I could find to make it budge from there.

It seems like the answer to your request is negative - this is the
way that Word has worked since the beginning, and that's probably
how it will continue to work. The code in Word that is responsible
for this mess is decades old, so no one will dare rewrite it all,
not mentioning that changing this might cause problems for millions
of existing documents.

Sorry for the negative answer.

Reference :
[Wrap text and move pictures in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wrap-text-and-move-pictures-in-word-becff26a-d1b9-4b9d-80f8-7e214557ca9f).